# Can my school website see my other tabs and/or applications on my desktop?

Tags: privacy

When I am at home taking an online exam through my school website (they use Blackbaud which allows teachers to set up assessments through a website), on my personal laptop, can that school website see other documents or other apps? I received an embarrassing text message during an exam and I'm wondering how much my teacher can see. I have not installed any software to my knowledge, just using my school's Blackbaud web browser.

Comment: hellow - *just using my school's Blackbaud web browser* - I'm not familiar with any *Blackbaud* software, however, your statement seems to imply that you have in fact installed custom browser software to take exams? Also, it's not clear to me how you received the text message - was this on another tab? Through some other service? Can you please edit your post to clarify these points?

Comment: When you are taking exam in your personal laptop from your home, your school may have control over the complete browser but not on anything else. Incase if your entire screen is being recorded during exam or if you used same browser for texting then your school may able to see that.